# Callback for transaction mined

Tags: solidity, nodejs

```
Coursetro.setFile(fileName,"test hash",function(error, result){
  if(!error)
  {
    console.log("Transaction submitted");
  }
  else{
    console.log("Error " + error);
  }
});
```

I am calling the above code in my Node.js controller. The callback is executed immediately when transaction is submitted.

Is there a callback invoked when a transaction gets successfully mined and is included in a block ? (Similar to Contract.new() web3js method that fires two callbacks )

Comment: What version of web3 are you using? With beta version 1.0.0 it does provide a callback when the transaction is mined. With stable version v0.20 you can create a block filter to listen new blocks being mined, and check the transaction hash was mined.

Comment: I used event.watch as my contract emits event at the end of setter method. It works for me.